# Is there any way to open Google Earth Engine images in Django and render it to leaflet?

Tags: django, leaflet

I want to open a Google Earth Engine image in Django and display it in a Leaflet. I have used the following codes for this:

```
l8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR").mean()
geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[[-80.92489760146748, 25.433457120928352],
                             [-80.64474623427998, 25.488013471687964],
                             [-80.57882826552998, 25.710940372707608],
                             [-81.02377455459248, 25.770317250349557],
                             [-80.95236342177998, 25.552457242621447]]]);

image  = image.filterBounds(geometry)
return JsonResponse({
    'image': image
})
```

and my template:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    zoomControl: false
})
```

now i want to show'image' on leaflet ap. Is there a way to do this?